# How to verify finished problem with laser reflection on a mirror (plane mirror)

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Definition of the problem

A laser is stationed at coordinates $(1,2,4)$, let us call this point $I$. The laser is pointing towards the mirror $\pi:2x-y-z=0$. The laser, after being reflected by the mirror, hits the point $R:(3,2,-2)$.

- What is the coordinates of the reflection point $P$ on the mirror?

---

#### My attempt at the solution

[image: Excuse me if the dimensions in the figure is messed up]

Because of how mirrors work, we get the isosceles triangle $PR_rR$ which I thought would help me solve the issue. If I could find the line that goes through $I$, and $R_r$, I could easily find the reflection point $P$.

Well, the direction vector for the normal of any plane of the form $\Theta:ax+by+cz+d=0$ is equal to $V:(a,b,c)$.

Therefore the line goes through $R$ and $R_r$ is:

$$L:\begin{cases}
x=3&+&2t \\
y=2&-&t \\
z=-2&-&t
\end{cases}$$

Put inside $\pi$ gives us $$2(3+2t)-(2-t)-(-2-t)=6+6t = 0 \iff t_0=-1$$

Because the distance from $R$ to $R_0$ is half the distance from $R$ to $R_r$ we get that the coordinates for $$R_r = L(2t_0) = (-1,4,0)$$

The lines that goes through $R_r$ and $I$ is therefore equal to

$$\zeta:\begin{cases}
x = 1 &+&t\\
y=2&-&t\\
z=4&+&2t
\end{cases}$$

Using $\zeta$ and $\pi$ we find: $2(1+t)-(2-t)-(4+2t)=-4+t\iff t_i=4$

This means the reflection point $P$ lies at the coordinates $\zeta(4) = (5,-2,12)$

- **How can this be verified?**

Comment: Your computation is correct. Why do you still want to verify it? Do you mean by experiment?

Comment: @KittyL I was thinking if there is some way to 'approve' of computations like these with some other approach. Such as looking at angles or something similar. Thank you for letting me know it is correct though :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to verify it is to calculate the angle between IP and the normal vector of $\pi$, and the angle between RP and the normal vector of $\pi$, and see if they are equal.

The normal vector of $\pi$ is $(2,-1,-1)$, $IP=(4, -4, 8)$, $RP=(2, -4, 14)$. The angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{||\vec{u}|| ||\vec{v}||}$. You can try that.

Comment: I tried this by using Wolfram, and the angle $IP\pi$ showed to be $\arccos\frac{1}{6}$ meanwhile the angle $RP\pi$ showed to be $\arccos-\frac{1}{6}$. They differ by ~0.33. Is my answer wrong then?

Comment: That would be the same. They are acute and obtuse. When we talk about angle between two directions, we use the acute one (positive value of cosine).

Comment: Very nice tips about looking at positive cosinus values as they are acute. Got rid of all my confusion. Thanks once again Kitty. You've been a great help!

Comment: You are welcome! :)